# Need to get 1st row of a common column entries but excluding row having specific column value

Tags: mysql

I need to get first rows from table 'category_vouchers' having same values in column id_new_record, but need to exclude assigned = 1[image]

my query also getting `assigned` = 1

```
select cv.id_voucher, nc.id, nc.name as value, nc.result_text as resultText, cv.assigned
    FROM category_vouchers cv 
    left JOIN category_vouchers cv2 ON (cv.id_new_record = 
        cv2.id_new_record AND cv.id_voucher > cv2.id_voucher) 
    inner join new_record nc on nc.id = cv.id_new_record 
    WHERE cv2.id_voucher IS NULL
```

I expect id_voucher 7 , 3 and 5

Comment: Can you say, what's version of MySQL?

Comment: i am using 
MySQL server version: 5.5.5-10.1.37-MariaDB

Comment: Just use `group by id_new_record` and `where assigned = 0`. You'll get first record per `id_new_record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply solve it using **SUBQUERY with JOIN**

```
select cv.id_voucher, nc.id, nc.name as value, nc.result_text as resultText, cv.assigned 
FROM category_vouchers cv 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM category_vouchers WHERE assigned = 0) cv2 ON ( cv.id_new_record = cv2.id_new_record AND cv.id_voucher > cv2.id_voucher) 
INNER JOIN new_record nc on nc.id = cv.id_new_record 
WHERE cv2.id_voucher IS NULL AND cv.assigned = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one

```
SELECT cv.id_voucher, nc.id, nc.name AS value, nc.result_text AS resultText, cv.assigned
FROM category_vouchers cv
LEFT JOIN category_vouchers cv2 ON (cv.id_new_record = cv2.id_new_record AND cv.id_voucher > cv2.id_voucher)
INNER JOIN new_record nc ON nc.id = cv.id_new_record
WHERE cv2.id_voucher IS NULL AND cv.assigned <> 1
GROUP BY cv.id_new_record
```

To remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from sql_mode

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
    SELECT cv.id_voucher, nc.id, nc.name as value, nc.result_text as resultText, cv.assigned     
    FROM category_vouchers cv INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT id_voucher, MIN(id_voucher) minid
            FROM category_vouchers
            where assigned != 1
            GROUP BY id_voucher
        ) t ON cv.id_voucher = t.id_voucher AND cv.id_voucher = t.minid
 inner join new_record nc on nc.id = cv.id_new_record WHERE cv2.id_voucher IS NULL
```